# Need Clarity how to detect and Swap the element before the element is removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I've created the video layout like the pip mode option

refer link -> *https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/poLmwmW*

and then I want to detect and swap to append the element before removing the video element tag.**

*I've tried this code, and I'm Using **DomNodeRemoved***

**Note**: *without the use of append and appendTo Method*

```
 // After Swapping removed PipMode
  $(".video-list ").on('DOMNodeRemoved', function (e) {
    if ($('.video-list .videoWrap').length > 0 && $('.mainVideo').length > 0) {
      var $AfterthisVideo = $(this).find('video')[0];
      console.log("this", $AfterthisVideo)
      var $AftermainVideo = $('.main-videoWrap').find('video')[0];
      console.log("main", $AftermainVideo)
      AfterSwap($AfterthisVideo, $AftermainVideo)
    }
  });

  function AfterSwap(AfterthisVideo, AftermainVideo) {

    AfterthisVideo.insertBefore(AftermainVideo, AfterthisVideo)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix this issue to detect the Dom Node Removed function, Thanks

```
 $(".video-list ").on('remove', function (e) {
    if ($('.video-list .videoWrap').length > 0 && $('.mainVideo').length > 0) {
      var $AfterthisVideo = $(this).find('video')[0];
      console.log("this", $AfterthisVideo)
      var $AftermainVideo = $('.main-videoWrap').find('video')[0];
      console.log("main", $AftermainVideo)
      AfterSwap($AfterthisVideo, $AftermainVideo)
    }
  });
```